# branding with type predicates in intersections

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, entity-component-system

I have a small problem that I've been unable to solve after several hours.
I don't know if a sharper mind could offer me a solution?

- I'm using a method that returns a predicates : `this is xxx`.
- It's used in an intersection with a branding.

But unfortunately, i can't seem to find a solution to allow this approach.
Maybe a lacking from typescript !?

Everything work as i want, but this thing drive me crazy :) !
If anyone has any ideas ho to remove this last error in my code ? see:

I've simplified the example to the minimum

thanks a lot

```
type RemoveSuper<A extends number[]> = { // remove number constructor in tuple [number,1,2] => [1,2]
    [K in keyof A]: number extends A[K] ? never : A[K]
}

type EntityWith<N extends number[] > = { //entity with numbers (branding) 
    has< T extends N >( componentType: T ):boolean
}

type ExtractGenericInIntersection<T> = (
    T extends Entity<infer C> ? ( c:C[number]) => void : never
) extends ( r: infer R2 ) => void ? [R2[]] : never

type Entities<T extends Entity> = ExtractGenericInIntersection<T> extends [infer R extends number[]]
    ? EntityWith<R> | Entity<R>
    : never

export interface Entity<C extends number[] = number[]> {
    has: <T extends RemoveSuper<C>[number]>( componentType: T ) => this is Entity<[T]>;
}
type A = Entity<[1]>
type B = Entity<[1, 2]>

declare const entities: Entities<A|B>;

//@ts-expect-error
entities.has( 2 );

entities.has( 1 );//
```

[tiny version](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/C4TwDgpgBAShC2B7AbhAygV0gJwDwEEoIAPYCAOwBMBnKcjeAIwmwG0BdAPigF4oBvKAHohUbAhTR6TFlADGictWDYMc4ImxQAluSjAsAG2itpzbABoAjBYBM7Xt1Y37AKACQrANI69AawgQRAAzKHx2AC46BnMiUgoaMO8HAH46CFQtKPxk1wBfV1dQSCgAUXJgbVAAdSqAC1wAOTiyKlozFg4obj5BEQpK0CgAd3romWxaAApGbABDKl0AcwBKKA86uepcKAAVFoTaZs4p+UR4MEUB3fAIKP2ViMZERGMF-MLi6FLSefUAcQoLG0cgAkuRwWRJhB1NpFLhdj0oFMPPsSK1EuVBiBcLpgrIAMLcNKnOQRAmmGIsdhrHjcZCIbSUKBRcgZFiuNbow7IsRRPGyGC2KC0+mM5lpVhCjgOVns7CfW5lCpVbQQbZo+JtZXYpE-FRzAFA7Ag8GQljUGGVeGIg7a1gCrQwO2JDpsdjsDxpLFVEC1YANGDcAA+Ot9uCDHjlmUKJEu2GAvihwUN3xVoFwBJd7Sp7t443MHG4-A2WyiCOzsAkqEwOEznEpEy4pPOlzZFRukHuIsc+jq2loA7DGdYuy4AG4Pl8wvmfSOrFwikqAEKz9M45wWKD2TiFSgwwxzcRnJSJgaq9VROdq7b4YPLziT1wiAACwGoAFo41av9hsJpXHPSp1QAOk2ahTmFFYnyAm8wK2U4rBFccREAXg3ABZd1wgA)

[short version](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/FAFwngDgpgBAwgewHYGcQCcCuBjED0A8AKgHwwC8MSUA7jABQB0zAhugOYoBcVUAblHQBKCmSIBuUJFiIAthGRQkIItOIwoADxBKAJingJ5i5RUPHqyspUSoMOPIVJToMAEpRZCAQGVM0QgBBDW09A0wkAGskBBokAG0AXWsYAG9gAEh4gGkYAEskGEioMAQAMxhAxJ45BUsQEJ0kfUqcxMyAfl4BdEyaozqlFWlGsNbs9oyu6h6+mCTR5oNAts7uwTmVieAAX3ikTFkAI0F2l1gAUWU88AB1G4ALAky4RZbakxAAGky3N4MPvVVK5KDNBD8Mhd-jAriAbmAzLD4T8UlCAGRpTLsKAgdRaJrvEj0bADT7AqD9CxDcnEEhCHhETIAeiZMCIAHkACIABhgPDyMF0yAa0ViMAeYpQCAANgIYCAHnkDABCGCAXg3ACy7mQeLBQeNCS3cRJJVOU5IZ9JgRwQMqgLCQu2AwBZVulLGwkRgshY7Dy2Bg0rt6GouhgLAaDxAIAg3BZaHdkW8gjK0tijBNTJYTIA7AA2AAcAE4ACzFgBMuaZAGYy9my2Wq-nzjDtOh3SAAOJKQR+gCSSH7OnQKCguDyyFpZlSOxgGPomSI0KR4AIBTKgncX3ySHX6BgAFkSGt6OgeG59ocTuhElvZDx9xfjqcROQyHwEHldHMwb0RPixie-I7hubhlreQG7geZYvm+H5flM8ygUkW77mWSSTDwP5Os2y55FAeqLv+hrLmAqKtu2XbUOgfYDsoggjmOE6kNC8RriB0KAkMyHbpB+4caSQLSOhawkfcCoEOeBxPteKGPleN5smQAA+MLXCubgoUeGSYfwGzACwRxoG2uAwNgbooACAlDJiGQAMSfmYPhgMcMr0EIkg7MAZm6pZpogMERHvFZpjpHZDmUE5LnSm5HleeZvmDMoABC-F+TZ9mhhFznWtF7mOvphkYO2pnxapcIrr8qWJSACw2MFNU3pkfGBQlZJCYkZicWa7XAGQoW6KObroLAw0sEKSDSgid4HpIGQDd5w0wNiIA8PqBIGB4Xi+P4ggSSQxr1eahh2FguD4LSMFspk81DbAOrcDAa1jJtSZ+AEBCHgdflHUQl0Kkq+QGCRBD9vGSDYFANKkFuSRkC6mryg8sBHG2zQFOwMAjp4VAIA0KD+Ao6ANBAw26H64b4eKgiwMqHT5ThalgIEZaIozBDIfE4DQOU5jVUlW5c1APNdf5yQM+VYBJSzlDAxzgvC-VVRHjdbCwCSdgaIzPC4fhBAkczMAqSRUtHkM8KMPd9Ai4EQhAA)

[long version](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/FAFwngDgpgBAwgewHYGcQCcCuBjED0A8AKgHwwC8MSUA7jABQB0zAhugOYoBcVUAblHQBKCmSIBuUJFiIAthGRQkIItOIwoADxBKAJingJ5i5RUPHqyspUSoMOPIVJToMAEpRZCAQGVM0QgBBDW09A0wkAGskBBokAG0AXWsYAG9gAEh4gGkYAEskGEioMAQAMxhAxJ45BUsQEJ0kfUqcxMyAfl4BdEyaozqlFWlGsNbs9oyu6h6+mCTR5oNAts7uwTmVieAAX3ikTFkAI0F2l1gAUWU88AB1G4ALAky4RZbakxAAGky3N4MPvVVK5KDNBD8Mhd-jAriAbmAzLD4T8UlCAGRpTLsKAgdRaJrvEj0bADT7AqD9CxDcnEEhCHhETIoHF40JLeBEklU5Q8eK2NBYXD4WlfGAII4AKyguES9JgfAQeV0mTKBV0rIJBjcnNJQOkDLlRBgAB8YBFdFBVdRlZkAPS2mBEADyABEAAwwHh5GC6ZANaKxGAPQMoBAAGwEMBADzyBgAhDBALwbgBZdu0Oh4sFAER3Q7X0GBcwbKckMmD0jwgTDoJA0i7xADkGZQ9eSaaDmezRvxYzzBd11P1Obl0dj+QMSPABAAknYWEhsFAaaRRUkyPb8lGY1FN6PRzEGgoUCg8kcw7BMk2NT2ddzhtADTwjghw1A57tgMB16eWNhIjBZCw7B5NgMBnmw1owCwDQPCAIAQNw9poD+kTeIIZRhrEjBcraLC2gA7AAbAAHAAnAALGRABMBG2gAzJReGUZRtFEecMLaOgP4gAA4kogjATOM46OgzK4HkyC0mYqQ7DAGL0JkXZsi0E5gAQBRlII7iiupmkALIkGs9DoDwbj7IcJzoIkoqyDwulmccpwiOQZAKkqMDriABg0HkYZhvkSAaegm6wNi1DoMBUYIP5wmiXCyAwEcCLduyZQRGJ8UQGwLCyAY9Dfr+-6AXkkRCHMYK9CIyUtEZXoBZpbiUdZtWBTAumUU5LmKsqUzzA1SSim1SSTDw5UfuuLC+YGLBmkg4mFOURQxHQQw3HkUAoGxE5rVmimajC1zgKiHFcbxYUCUgQmCLFc2SVVBjxDpQV-Hd5hFiA-X+S1unQoCA7QENawqfc0YEKZBwOZZA32RZVmOmQpoqaDA0GRkI38BsY32g6U66QACgAMhcukXAAckQgREFOTokz4wAsEcApcQWYaZgC-amOkGRIXCIE0OFOgEK8L2-cW0hEiO3DwKKuhQSwPC42wcITdOs7zouahwCQdK8nAorgNAC0yyALCJJiGQZOgOJVoU8QS9LsuJJIGQ7B+GQAMRuZQPhgMc4b0EITuWywvpIGGCIknYgqOOSZgS1hyACg4+CQWzkdJ4QIsgCQkgu9gLNHq9nzBML7MNJzHu6GY3u+2G-tO96lAkTnwB56zhf1AAQj9pdmxXVc+0+tcB++rcF5nQtKWzt5mw8ZhN5kfdewPfvD7n+dT29Lrd9P5eezA1eD3XI-r+3QxQiXO8L3vB8r83o8b58ABi29vb31-L0PTssFAP9mAArHfE+mduIv0+G-SuS8a5HwyD-WAlAiLNzpgzDATN777ThJOX4oD6gLBsKXfqmRvoXzeuSXBp9Rb-XaGQTm3MIoR1VOwZ45sI5oHcNgoYBDmEJwaEQye5C7xQE4USTIGR6F5HYCZCEGQAJgBOLZTIIhOYZHpozXAzM24AH0NGIxERkNwz0+GZzIW4KRGRdK8L2pnUhptKC6SkWQF6EtQZ-FNCY1q31TT6UxCIl25tLaVmrDALRKknYu0yBaVulsYBBxDmHaJJknYRJZlEmJyA4k2VapIV2SS2AhRxDwK87IPBeF8P4QQoMtbElLiWQwachRODpKIR04TpTJNgMyEABTdo9k8KhPwAQKk3jejrbhUdhTLjFJKaUIBZRNNcjaDIOSolWl0F03MvTSkDP0kMskg4iAdRzKac0loChQG6ks2ATY1kvWKX0sphBtlVNvDU-ZTSJZjnQfCFWSE1ZLhICuZI7kHQpmCglTizQCjsBgMyTwVAEANBQP4BQ6ADyW10MBKC60gyCFgHGDoH4wnrgAAKeQALTiJiFE0lkUooZnQJXPA0LwyRnoJ5UCeRZA3DOZBZoBY5zQTnLoM8fY6mOE+jitWIrE71P9qkRFAQmDMEekIHYpUVEoLUWglS3FspQCYQYyx+CbH8M4RYsYVjpBkItZQ4ADi+EqXjgFcR8ksgiOoHQYB-sIRWUyHyUuFwzhCCRq1ahTJjY8zFD0cKFoRUMKYaI7hbDiGfE4QmuwrV2EUMET6jIwiuFOokVpERMi5GtQUWbZRyDOKapPsEg6YBdJKiFXq3R+jM3vWNSY3R5j23WLMLpERdq9pOLba4gaHiQ0Vt8RbK2gS60YIbU2s8oT3wtxPipYu9r606tkFAR1DCXXxDdbQfhgQvXHo9aXOA56Mg5r9beR+opM4d3aIogla624qS7i9bVur93Ot9Re-hHcb0ZHdfw69QhvUQnvW9R+r7MSEqxo6C4PhGQsIaNNUEJ6N1HwwwlMw4Gv14YTi+RgGF2D0HrFwesK4WCiiOLKSQmBmRbXWoEfAIGWDDxY1ANjKAOPoBA0cHjzId18frfQbjWT7QkpQKSrQ0BcAKfQOgZO1LBC9F41x4eeQKhScYE2egz6hBvoyNpqTq9MYwAABJTm4jZo0hMABqFx8aVFxlOFDaHgCpXnHFQoFmVrgB4EDR4gtS4d0aZzYLYBGDYhAMZyLw80xyYU5oJTIAVNqaChp1TmRYvxZxElh9VnfNpQC2aZkgQQOxdC-W4GTxn0mlPdFgr9aiuJczoEYeMCOsJZK29DuKWMiybJYp6Z2X1MaHy31hdnXBufDgFZvz6VAtibPXVz5dxwvAJa91trc34QLe671wrA3gEjbG-JibynNPTc0+1+bF3-UrYq3NKrUBr1bbCyDceh3zvFfHld20aXbtZfu7lmbvQjvgBO6Xbib3-Mfd47pFgsi+OP3oD9hr4Xyp62kAtTOUJTT6ygET0uj8AcdZWYt+oFwzs07VHToYj8Qdg4y5NyHMA8sw8K7T07zdVuVd49xWQm3631YXY1iLt5uIE4NhUA7Zn8MrLMPz5ngvMh6YYIVozp2zMuxdsLlHYndUqWx5L7bYBxNvuN+9+KvH+OCdq1b-jBAN0ta-Yd676XMtTah492HcWXu3h607fDIFKCA661ekbhWOks+UHARgfMuX0FSEGHgREYCqvZ+Nznd3VMPdm91xgMTLcLvzzdwvEPi+B9mzHpPIA2dZNG6Dgv-vue88yLxmrlf4TV791z+vPPoe942wP8AQ-wcB7H0H0XEuq9O1499+tI3Ufo5OBcLHsWZ+17nz34PhnMzN-D67X3s-u-j+PwL5LbfL8H+v0HpvmdW-a-03r0-b-TMVtf5T3rW-TXAAldF2IAA)

Comment: @jcalz You are right, I managed to rethink and reduce it to ~50 lines without context and security. The conflict is much clearer now i think, I have edited the code and link.

Comment: Thanks. It's still more complicated than I can process, unfortunately. It's a big mess of intersections and unions and generic conditional types.  `RemoveSuper` and `ExtractGenericInIntersection` written inside the types make it quite confusing. I expect you'd be able to reproduce the fundamental issue with some toy example you build up from scratch rather than whittling it down from your code base. Unless that happens I'm just going to shrug and move on to preserve my sanity. Sorry I can't be of more help.

Comment: oki no problem, i will think about a tiny fundamental primitive example with maybe with numbers :)

Comment: @jcalz tiny version with number is available, However, I think I cannot reduce it further. I am probably just facing a limitation of TypeScript: branding cannot be supported with predictions!? I suppose I will have to refrain from using this method in my API. It's not dramatic, but it disturbs me not to be able to take advantage of it!

Comment: my english is limited , i said branding with type predicates in intersections but am not sure if is the correct english vocabulairy for this issue

Comment: ① In the tiny version `entities.has()`  is a union of methods where one expects an input of type `1` and the other expects an input of type `1[]`. Such a method cannot be called because there are no compatible inputs of type `1 & 1[]`.  If you expect something else please review your example. ② How does `RemoveSuper<C>[number]` differ from `C[number]` meaningfully enough to be included here?

Comment: juste solved , https://discord.com/channels/508357248330760243/1212538107086372894
i will add the fix in 2 day when i will be authorized

"changed` EntityWith` into an interface" interface can handle `this` but not type !
I am so used to seeing people say that types do everything that interfaces do, that I forgot about some abilities of interfaces! like support of `this`

Comment: fix at line 21: https://tsplay.dev/wX0lOw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related to a limitation of `type` that do not handle `this`.

`Interfaces` seem to support `this`, which allows branding works.

By replacing type with interface the branding work.

```
type EntityWith<
    C extends Component,
    R extends ComponentType = never,
    E extends Entity = Entity,
> = E & {
    has<T extends R>(componentType: T): boolean
}
```

by

```
interface EntityWith<
    C extends Component,
    R extends ComponentType = never,
> extends Entity {
    has< T extends R>( componentType: T ): this is Entity<InstanceType<T>, []>
}
```

Now it reflet correcly the method in class

```
abstract class Entity {
    declare has: <T extends RemoveSuper<M>>(componentType: T) => this is Entity<InstanceType<T>, []>
}
```